# Excel: Dynamic population based on text in another cell

Tags: excel

I am hoping someone can give me some MS Excel help.  I have a column that lists a series of Jira Epics.  Based on the value in that cell I'm looking to populate a different cell with specific text.

Unfortunately I'm not able to put screenshots in so I'll try and lay it out without that.

```
A1= Project#1: O&M/Production Support/Defect FY22Q4
B1= Team_A
A2= Project#1: Enhancement FY22Q4
B1= Team_B
A3= Project#2: O&M/Production Support/Defect FY22Q4
B1= Team_C
A4= Project#2: Enhancement FY22Q4
B1= Team_A
A5= Project#3: O&M/Production Support/Defect FY22Q4
B1= Team_B
A6= Project#3: Enhancement FY22Q4
B1= Team_C
```

What I am trying to do is create a formula (trying to avoid VB code since I don't have access to run it) that does the following in a cell that's in column C

```
C1 would = Team_A O&M
C2 would = Team_B Enh
C3 would = Team_C O&M
C4 would = Team_A Enh
C5 would = Team_B O&M
C6 would = Team_C Enh
```

If that's not possible I can go with the lest optimal solution of only using data form the cells in column A.

```
C1= Project#1 O&M
C2= Project#1 Enh
C3= Project#2 O&M
C4= Project#2 Enh
C5= Project#3 O&M
C6= Project#3 Enh
```

Comment: Use a [Mark down table to explain this better](https://www.tablesgenerator.com/markdown_tables)

Comment: ^^^^ Or upload the images to http://imgur.com and link to them

Comment: Markdown table allows for copy-paste to replicate... so more likely to be helpful.

Comment: Also some values don't make sense. `B1` has different values.

Answer (score 0):

Put this in C1 and copy it down:
`=B1&" "&MID(A1,FIND(":",A1,1)+2,3)`